# Why are all devices sitting on USB 3.0 eXtensible Controller and none on USB Enhanced?

Tags: windows-7, usb-3, wireless-mouse, usb-2, wireless-keyboard

I'm having a bit of a strange issue here with some USB controllers and devices.

I'm working with a Dell T5810 workstation, Windows 7 x64 with various USB devices connected.

- Mouse, Keyboard and/or Logitech Unifying Receiver (Sometimes all for testing)
- (2) USB 3.0 external HDs (one continuous, 2nd periodically)
- USB 2.0 Audio DAC
- USB 3.0 Scanner
- Other transient devices, like card readers, etc.

I was having a bit of hiccup and jitter whenever I'd connect this one USB 3.0 external chassis.  I've been noticing for the past week that that my wireless keyboard was lagging with extremely long delays, or just wouldn't respond at all (confirmed not battery related).

I also noticed this with a wireless mouse long ago and just thought it faulty.

Working through some sound quality hiccups with an audio vendor, we used USBView to inventory controllers and devices. **I'm attaching a screenshot of the USB Controllers and device locations at the bottom of this post.**

**It looks to me that ALL USB connected devices are on the USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller, even though some are not plugged into USB 3.0 ports on the machine.**  I would have expected to see only devices connected to USB 3.0 ports to show up here?

Also, why all these extra "ports" when I don't have that many physical ports?

- 4 rear (marked 3 - USB 3.0, 1 enhanced)
- 2 rear (low power/enhanced for mouse keyboard? Next to the ethernet port)
- 4 front panel (marked 1 - USB 3.0, 3 enhanced)

I've since added an older NEC chipped USB 2.0 controller card that I planned to use to isolate the audio DAC.  That part works great, now, incidentally.

I have VMware Workstation installed on this machine, though not currently running.  Not sure whether this may have anything to do with the additional "ports".

I've also tried two different Logitech Unifying Receivers, and in different ports.  Oddly seems that one of the devices, either the keyboard, or mouse, suffers debilitating lag as soon as I connect that second USB 3.0 disk enclosure, depending on the port used for the Unifying receiver.

Any ideas what's going on here and why there are no USB 2.0/Enhanced devices on the C610 Chipset USB Enhanced Controller?  **Ideally, I only want my high speed devices on my 3.0 controller/ports and everything else on Enhanced for the purpose of isolation.** I think this has something to do with the lag and hiccups I've been seeing while I have these disks connected, especially with larger file copy operations.

**Seems to only affect wireless mouse and keyboard. Interference?**

Second, how can I get these devices isolated on separate USB controllers that are installed, or is eXtensible USB a front end that consolidates the mainboard USB ports?

**Screenshot**
[USBView Screenshot of USB Controllers and Device Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhWpQ.png)

Comment: [Your PC appears to have 3 USB 2.0 ports and 3 3 USB 3.0 ports.](http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/desktop-and-all-in-one-pcs/precision-5810-tower/spd/precision-t5810-workstation)  "why all these extra "ports" when I don't have that many physical ports?" - Where?  Your question appears to be missing vital information.  Take a minute to organize your thoughts.

Comment: Change batteries in Logitech devices.  Also run the Logitech Unifying utility, click on "Advanced" on the first screen, and remove any other paired devices to the adapter.

Comment: You're looking at something that's making you think you have extra ports and making you think that all USB devices are on the XHC. But you don't tell us what you're looking at or what it's showing you, just the conclusions you drew from it. The solution may be as simple as not drawing those conclusions.

Comment: Forgot to attach the screenshot of the USBView, showing the USB Controllers and Device locations.  Adjusted original post to include this now.

USB Composite Device is the Logitech Unifying Receiver, and Logitech USB WheelMouse is a separate wired mouse I've got sitting on the system at the moment.

The NEC PCI to USB Enhanced is the separate add-in card.

The C610 series USB Enhanced and USB 3.0 eXtensible controllers are native.

Comment: Anyone had a look at that screenshot showing the device locations?  Again, my goal here is for device isolation in order to avoid any interference or hiccups during heavy disk intensive operations with the external storage devices.

Comment: I did manage to improve the wireless mouse/keyboard performance issue by using a USB cable to connect to the USB hub built into the primary Dell U2412M display.  I was reading that USB 3.0 devices can cause wireless interference, and the recommendation was to place wireless device receivers away from USB 3.0 connections.  I wasn't sure whether this meant on physically different controllers or just proximity wise.

Comment: So, half of this problem seems to be improved, if not resolved.  Plugging the Logitech Unifying Receiver into one of the USB ports on the bottom of the display gets it away from any connections to USB 3.0 storage devices.  I imagine that use of a shielded USB 3.0 cable may also help with this.  This begs another question - who makes quality USB 3.0 cables?  I've had more drop-outs with extended data transfers of large amounts of data since adopting USB 3.0 storage for backup purposes.  Even with included cables from "quality" vendors, like Drobo.